# Check to see if getIntent().getStringExtra() is empty?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing a simple android app that has a dynamic `ListView` associated with an `ArrayList`. The user can type in a text box, press a button, and the text will be added to the `ListView` via the `ArrayList`. The text box where the user can type is on a separate activity, so whenever the user presses "submit" in order to add the item to the `ListView`, the main activity is called and the text is passed via an `intent`. I need to check to see if the text was empty, however, because otherwise the way my code is setup an empty entry to the `ListView` will be added. This is what I currently have:

```
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ArrayAdapter<Item> itemsAdapter = new itemsListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, itemsArrayList);
    ListView itemsListView = findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_itemsListView1);
    itemsListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    String incomingItemName = getIntent().getStringExtra("ITEM_NAME");
    if (!incomingItemName.equals("")) { itemsArrayList.add(new Item(incomingItemName)); } //this line causes app to crash on start
    }
```

The `if` statement I have written causes the app to crash on startup, if I comment that line out the app starts fine. If I move `itemsArrayList.add(new Item(incomingItemName));` out of an `if` statement, a blank list entry is created when the user goes into the activity to add an item then simply backs out back into the main screen.

I am relatively new to android programming, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your stack trace in your question to people can help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Textutils.isEmpty()` to check your string from intent. It will return `true` if your input string is null or empty.

Comment: Thank you. That worked beautifully, I will accept this as the answer as soon as it will let me.